# Did a lightning strike make a river roll and boil?

Tags: physics, lightning

There's a video that I just came across on Facebook:

- original source: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TD2hyCUePL0
- alternative copy: https://www.facebook.com/hardbond/videos/10155610316509339/

In the video it shows what appears to be lightning travelling nearly horizontal and striking a river. The river launches up as if there were an underwater explosion for about 20-30 feet, and then rolls around. The video currently has 16 million views.

Lightning doing weird things I'm totally comfortable with - it's just not something we understand very well. But would it have that effect on the water, or is something else at play there?

Comment: Doesn't even really look like lightning to be honest.  Looks more so like some kind of initiator that creates an electric discharge similar to that of a tesla coil.  Not sure if they did that for a cool factor to trigger the explosion or if it legitimately needs that form of surge to set it off.

Comment: can you provide a better source? There is just an login screen and the video does not play.

Comment: @JonasStein here's the original source, from youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TD2hyCUePL0

Comment: The amount of energy needed to flash-boil a river is difficult to comprehend.  I've got a 3kw electric kettle and that takes over a minute to boil a litre of water.  Lightning can be very energetic, but I seriously doubt even the biggest known strike has the energy to do that.  We are talking several dozen metric tons of water here!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**This is not a lightning strike.  It's an underwater blasting explosion**

Snopes covered this a few days ago.  Here's the [article](http://www.snopes.com/lightning-striking-a-river/).  The [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TD2hyCUePL0) was originally posted to YouTube in 2012 to host it for this [website](http://www.merityo.fi/louhinta).

The site says:

> KÄÄNNY VEDENALAISESSA LOUHINTA- JA RÄJÄYTYSTYÖSSÄ AINA ASIANTUNTIJAN
> PUOLEEN
>
> Rantojen ja vedenalaisen kallion louhinta- ja rakennustyö
> Turun saaristossa ja ympäristössä. Vedenalaisessa louhinnassa
> madalletaan kallionpinnan korkeutta järvessä, meressä tai muussa
> vesistössä. Ennen louhintatyön aloittamista tehdään louhinta- ja
> räjäytystöiden suunnitelma, jotta kaikki toteutuu turvallisesti.
> Vesistössä tapahtuva kallion louhinta on luvanvaraista toimintaa ja
> saattaa vaatia aluehallintoviraston (AVI) luvan.
>
> MIHIN VEDENALAINEN
> LOUHINTA SOVELTUU?
>
> Vedenalaista louhintaa käytetään rantojen ja
> vesistöjen kunnostukseen sekä merimerkkien perustamiseen. Lisäksi
> vesiväylien syventäminen, rakentaminen ja ylläpito tehdään louhinta-
> ja räjäytystöillä. Louhinta suoritetaan laittamalla porausreikiin
> vedenalaista erikoisräjähdettä, joka upotetaan kallioon porattuihin
> reikiin. Asiakkaita voi olla yksityiset asiakkaat, satamat, ja
> venesatamat. Ympäristöhallinnon sivuilta voit lukea lupa-asioista
> enemmän.

According to Google Translate (I don't speak or read Finnish so feel free to improve the translation if you do):

> TAKE UNDERWATER MINING AND BLASTING WORK TO AN EXPERT
>
> Mining and
> construction of beaches and underwater rock in Turku archipelago and
> surroundings. Underwater quarrying lowers the rock surface level in
> the lake, ocean or other waters. Before the excavation work is
> started, a mining and blasting plan is planned to ensure that
> everything is safely accomplished. The rock mining in water requires
> a license and may require the permission of the regional government
> agency (AVI).
>
> WHERE IS UNDERWATER QUARRYING SUITABLE?
>
> Underwater
> quarrying is used for the improvement of beaches and waterways and
> the creation of navigational beacons. In addition, the deepening, construction
> and maintenance of waterways are carried out through mining and blasting
> operations. Extraction is carried out by placing a special submerged
> explosive into the drilling holes, which is inserted into drilled holes
> in the rock. Our clients can be private customers, ports, and marinas.
> From the Environmental Administration website, read more about
> licensing issues .

Comment: Jeez, the Youtube title on the original upload even cleanly translates to "Drilling rig, part 3: Blasting" in Google Translate.

Comment: Makes me wonder whether it was extreme ignorance or just malice that got it from "blasting" to "lightning strike"

Comment: @WayneWerner click baiting almost certainly

Comment: @WayneWerner At first everyone thought they were just click baiting, but what happened next will blow your [mind](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0)